# How do I model the Expected Value in a trial and error until find some value?

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem I was thinking is: Supose you have **m** pieces of cake and  **n** of them are spoiled, I start picking one piece, if it's normal I take it out and continue doing this until I find one spoiled.

What is the expected value of cakes I catch before the spoiled? I thought it could be something geometric but the probabilities change. How can I attack this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can also compute it directly

$$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-m}i\frac{n-(i-1)}{m}\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(1-\frac{n-j}{m})$$

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer assumes sampling with replacement. Sampling without replacement is a bit more complicated, but this should lead you in the right direction.

This looks to be a homework question, so I will go through the steps a little more carefully and allow you to finish it.

The first thing we need to ask is "What probability distribution is this?" In our situation, there are 2 values: Spoiled and not spoiled. Many can work in this situation, but since we know that this is like a coin flip with many coins, we can say it's likely a binomial distribution.

We then ask "What is an expected value?" The short answer is that it is the mean of the collected data, so we will treat it like a simple mean. But this question isn't actually about the expected value, we are asking "how many successes until failure", where failure is finding a bad piece. So instead, we ask, what is the probability of 0 successes? Then of 1 success? Then 2? Then 3? Etc.

Thus, we need a formula for the probability of each. For the binomial, this is
$$P = {w\choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n=k}$$

To make it easier though, we can instead ask, what is the probability of each result? Using S for success (not rotten) and F for failure (rotten) we see

F - $ n/m$

SF - $(1-n/m)(n/m)$

SSF - $(1-n/m)^2(n/m)$

SSSF - $(1-n/m)^3(n/m)$

And so on. We thus multiply by each value of input and get
$N = n/m + 2 * (1-n/m)(n/m) + 3 * (1-n/m)^2(n/m) + 4 * (1-n/m)^3(n/m) + ...$

This should slowly bring you to a right answer if you do this a total of (n-m) times, so you find the probability for each result. This actually tells you the total number of pulls including failures, so subtract 1 from the exponents for just the successes.

Comment: You're assuming we're sampling with replacement when the problem wants us to consider the case when we're sampling without replacement. Also, your probability of an event like SSSF is $(1-n/m)^3\cdot (n/m)$. There's no binomial coefficient out front.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Ah yeah, you're right about that. I'll drop the coefficients with a quick edit, and add a note on the replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{G_1,\ldots,G_{m-n}\}$ denote the $m-n$ "good" pieces of cake and $\{B_1,\ldots,B_n\}$ denote the $n$ "bad" pieces of cake. Define $X$ the be the random variable which counts the number of pieces of cake you sample until you obtain your very first "bad" piece of cake. Note that $X$ is supported on the set $\{1,\ldots,m-n+1\}$.

Regarding $\{G_1G_3B_4\}$ and $\{G_3G_1B_1\}$ as two distinct outcomes corresponding to the event that $X=3$ we see that $$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{^{m-n}P_{x-1}\times n}{^m P _x}$$Therefore $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{x=1}^{m-n+1}x\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\frac{m+1}{n+1}$$

Comment: in the first equation, is that a tetration?

Comment: @Roman $^nP_r=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ counts the nunber of ordered samples of $r$ objects when sampling among a group of $n$ objects without replacement.